# How to add facebook and twitter links in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, twitter

I've a task in which i need to add Face book LIKE, Comment etc buttons or links in my application. 
and also i need to add twitter link.

Please help me with the asp.net code.

Thank u.

Comment: What have you already tried, what worked, what didn't? 'Show me the codez' style questions don't tend to get a good response around here.

Comment: have you started with facebooks reference doc?: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/  It really doesn't get much easier than copy/paste....

Comment: i want to add facebook like button..how to get the code for that

Answer (score 1):

[Document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) provides links for Facebook Social Plugins such as (Like Button, Send button, Comments, Like Box.etc).

[Document](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites) for the Tweet button, Follow button and how can you embed them on your website with just one line of code.